# type error module object is not iterable error in django

Tags: django

C:\IT Career\Python\shop>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 600, in url_patterns
iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 413, in check
messages.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 412, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "C:\Users\THE KING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 607, in url_patterns
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '<module 'products.urls' from 'C:\IT Career\Python\shop\products\urls.py'>' does not appear to have any
patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider formatting your post and include the relevant piece of code.

Comment: kindly include urls.py file in you question. Also as per trace back it seems \products\urls.py file don't have a valid url pattern or its not in correct format. I think you have a typo there url_patterns  instead of urlpatterns correct the same and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i think you dont have `urlpatters` in `urls.py`. There must be a list that contains `paths` or `urls`.

Your `urls.py` should look something like this-:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views 
app_name = "<your_app_name>"

urlpatterns = [
            path("your_url", views.your_view),
            path("second_url/",views.second_view)]
```

Comment: got it thnk you